# How to organize DataArrays with different coordinate values

Tags: python, database, python-xarray

I have several xarray `DataArray` with 2 Coordinates `da1`, `da2`, `da3`,.... with the following shape:

```py
print(da1)

<xarray.DataArray 'Sa' (y: 5498, x: 200)>
[1099600 values with dtype=float64]
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 0.1457 0.1462 0.1467 0.1472 ... 2.893 2.893 2.894 2.894
  * x        (x) float64 3.985 3.975 3.965 3.955 ... 2.863 2.859 2.855 2.85
```

Each of these DataArrays corresponds to a sample with a certain name. I would like to create a unique structure that organizes all the DataArrays including the "sample name" information.

**The problem is that the `x` and `y` coordinate values are not the same among the DataArrays**, therefore creating a concatenated DataArray with a new coordinate `sample name` using `xr.concat` is not efficient, because it will create a lot of NaNs. Due to this, the `xr.concat` procedure is also very slow if the DataArrays are very large.

Do you know of a clever way to solve this issue in an efficient way? Possibly something that could work with any number of additional dimensions (e.g. a `date` coordinate in addition to the `sample name` coordinate).

Comment: Personally speaking, I prefer using `geopandas`. In this module, you can create geospatial dataframes that do not have same CRS(Coordinate Reference System). By using `to_crs` function, you can easily change the CRS to the desired one and the join dataframes to each other.

Comment: In my case I'm not working with coordinate reference systems, but with simple floats in the `x` and `y` coordinates, so does it still make sense? I cannot really see the connection with crs. In my view, all my coordinates are in the same crs, it's just that they have different values.